# Access Update Query Unique Criteria in multiple column

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have a table like this (Access Version 2013)

```
Block   SAP SAG BAP BAG 
600400  1   3        
600401          1   3 
600402              
600403  1   3   2   4 
600404          1   3 
600405          3   4 
600406  1   4        
600407  1   2   1   3
600408  4   5        
600409  1   1   3   1
600410  1   5   1   3
```

I want to update the table like this below, basically I want to null the (SAP & SAG = NULL) if (SAP = 1 AND SAG = 3), this one i can achieve easily, problem is I want to do the same for (BAP & BAG = NULL) if (BAP = 1 AND BAG = 3) without affecting SAP and SAG, i tried various ways, but end up with unusual result

```
Block   SAP SAG BAP BAG 
600400            
600401              
600402              
600403          2   4 
600404              
600405          3   4 
600406  1   4        
600407  1   2      
600408  4   5        
600409  1   1   3   1
600410  1   5
```

Is it possible to achieve with a single query (or) I need to use two different  update query ? Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two queries, because they affect different (but overlapping) sets of rows.

It's also simple and readable. Why would you not want to use two queries?

```sql
UPDATE foo 
SET SAP = NULL, SAG = NULL
WHERE SAP = 1 AND SAG = 3;

UPDATE foo 
SET BAP = NULL, BAG = NULL
WHERE BAP = 1 AND BAG = 3;
```

Comment: Because, this is just an example which I have posted in here, actually I got to add more than 30 columns to update, so I don't want to create too many update table.

Comment: You can create and run each UPDATE SQL in a VBA loop. But that would be for a new question.

Comment: I want exactly the same kind of loop using a macro or something !

Comment: Please ask a new question for that, with sample data that has more columns (e.g. 4*2).

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need to modify the first table, then its much simpler to NOT select the items you dont want, using access functions.

SELECT Iif(Sap<>"1" AND Sag<>"3"; Sap, "") AS SAP, Iif(Sap<>"1" AND Sag<>"3"; Sag, "") AS SAG,  Iif(Bap<>"1" AND Bag<>"3"; Bap, "") AS BAP,  Iif(Bap<>"1" AND Bag<>"3"; Bag, "") AS BAG FROM Table;